# Smoothening a function at an isolated point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that

1) $f$ is smooth, except for some point $p_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$

2) $\nabla f(x)\neq0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash\{p_{0}\}$ , (here
$\nabla$ is the gradient).

My question:

Can we find for any ball $B$ centered at $p_{0}$ a function $g:\mathbb{R}%
^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

1) $g$ is smooth in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

2) $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash B$

3) $\nabla g(x)\neq0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash\{p_{0}\}$.

In such a way, we are smoothening $f$ at point $p_{0}$ without destroying the
non-vanishing condition on the gradient in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash\{p_{0}%
\}$. Note that $p_{0}$ may become a critical point of $g$.